# Jekyll and GitHub Pages Site Not Displaying Favicon

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, favicon

I'm trying to get a favicon to appear on a Jekyll GitHub Pages site. I'm using the [Bulma Clean Theme](https://github.com/chrisrhymes/bulma-clean-theme) and have placed a PNG favicon in the project's main directory. However, the favicon does not appear in my web browser (Chrome).

The theme's [documentation](https://github.com/chrisrhymes/bulma-clean-theme#favicon) states, "The default favicon path is {{ site.baseurl }}/favicon.png but you can overwrite it in the sites _config.yml like this favicon: /path/to/favicon.png". I have not changed the default favicon path.

The site is https://nlakritz.github.io/ach, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is working (tested on Chrome 84.0).
But then also if it is not working for you, then avoid using `shortcut` in `rel="shortcut icon"`, such that `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon.png">`.